# Facebook like box with age restrictions is not working with administrator accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am an administrator for a Facebook page that has *Age Restrictions* set to *Alcohol-Related*.

I understand that fb-like-box should not be visible to users that are not logged in. This is working as expected for normal users. However, being an administrator, even if I am logged in with my Facebook personal account, the box is not visible. (If I remove age restriction it starts to work for my account too.)

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

EDIT: I also tried with a test account (the one you can create in your application) without success.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the reason. I was using Chrome web browser and I had *Block third-party cookies and site data* enabled.